# Please help me change a font

Tags: fonts

I found this template online. I'm trying to change the playful font that's in the title to this one: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/comfortaa/

I thought it's this section:

```
% Define Title en News input
\newcommand{\JournalName}[1]{%
    \begin{center}  
        \Huge \usefont{U}{xl}{n}{comfortaa} %\usefont{T1}{comfortaa}{m}{n}
        #1%
    \end{center}    
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}
```

But it doesn't work.
Where in this code is the usage specified?

Here's the template: https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/newsletter-template/nzvznvdbdqpl

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX Template: Newsletter  % Source: http://www.howtotex.com
%
% Feel free to distribute this example, but please keep the referral
% to howtotex.com
% Date: September 2011  
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   How to use writeLaTeX: 
% You edit the source code here on the left, and the preview on the
% right shows you the result within a few seconds.
%
%\title{Newsletter Template}

%%% ---------------
%%% PREAMBLE
%%% ---------------
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Define geometry (without using the geometry package)
\setlength\topmargin{-48pt}
\setlength\headheight{0pt}
\setlength\headsep{25pt}
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}
\setlength\textwidth{7.0in}
\setlength\textheight{9.5in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-30pt}
\setlength\evensidemargin{-30pt}

\frenchspacing                      % better looking spacing

% Call packages we'll need
\usepackage[english]{babel}         % english
\usepackage{graphicx}               % images
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}        % math
\usepackage{multicol}               % three-column layout
\usepackage{url}                    % clickable links
\usepackage{marvosym}               % symbols
\usepackage{wrapfig}                % wrapping text around figures
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % font encoding
\usepackage{charter}                % Charter font for main content
\usepackage{blindtext}              % dummy text
\usepackage{datetime}               % custom date
\newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\usepackage[pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
        colorlinks=false]{hyperref} % links and pdf behaviour

% Customize (header and) footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{ \footnotesize 
    Science \& Technology Newletter \\

    \Mundus\ \href{http://www.howtotex.com}{HowToTeX.com}   \quad
    \Telefon\ 555-5555                                          \quad
    \Letter\ \href{mailto:frits@howtotex.com}{frits@howtotex.com}
  }


\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize ~\\ Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}    % no bar on top of page
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}    % bar on bottom of page

%%% ---------------
%%% DEFINITIONS
%%% ---------------

% Define separators
\newcommand{\HorRule}[1]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Creating a             
 horizontal rule
\newcommand{\SepRule}{\noindent                          % Creating a 
separator
                    \begin{center}
                        \rule{250pt}{1pt}
                    \end{center}
                    }                       

% Define Title en News input
\newcommand{\JournalName}[1]{%
    \begin{center}  
        \Huge \usefont{T1}{augie}{m}{n}
        #1%
    \end{center}    
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\JournalIssue}[1]{%
    \hfill \textsc{\mydate \today, No #1}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewsItem}[1]{%
    \usefont{T1}{augie}{m}{n}   
    \large #1 \vspace{4pt}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewsAuthor}[1]{%
        \hfill by \textsc{#1} \vspace{4pt}
        \par \normalfont}       


%%% ---------------
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
%%% ---------------
\begin{document}
% Title 
% -----
\JournalIssue{1}
\JournalName{Science \& Technology}
\noindent\HorRule{3pt} \\[-0.75\baselineskip]
\HorRule{1pt}
% -----

% Front article
% -----
\vspace{0.5cm}
    \SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.75\linewidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.41\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
    \\  % this spacer is needed to make the text on the right fit OK
\end{wrapfigure}

\NewsItem{Frog eats monkey}
\emph{\blindtext}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
% -----


% Other news (1)
% -----
\vspace{0.5cm}
\SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\NewsItem{Monkey eats elephant}
\NewsAuthor{F. Wenneker}
\blindtext[2] 
% -----

\vspace{1cm}
% Other news (2)
% -----
\NewsItem{Elephant eats frog}
\NewsAuthor{J. Doe}
\blindtext[1]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{elephant}
    \end{center}
    \blindtext[1]
\end{multicols}
% -----
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE!

Comment: The first code-snippet was supposed to be that. I provided the whole template because I don't know what I'd need to change in order to change the font.

Comment: Can you test if http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/comfortaa/comfortaa.tex works for you? Then we would know that everything necessary is installed.

Comment: Good day to you. I would like to talk to you about [MWEs](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/117274).

Comment: Also, out of the blue, maybe it doesn't work just because you don't have comfortaa installed on your machine.

Comment: comfortaa Works. @samcarter that is where I loaded the front form. When I start from scratch, the font works. I'd like to use that template though. And just change that one font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The family name of the font is fco:

```
\documentclass{article} %or article
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\usefont{T1}{fco}{m}{n} blub
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks, but why fco? Where would I know that from?

Comment: I looked in the code, it is not so long ...

Comment: That code does not contain 'fco' ? I probably need to learn about fonts, because I don't understand how you knew that

Comment: The code of confortaa.sty does contain fco.

Comment: What is the reason `\usefont{comofrtaa}` does not work? Where is that specified?

Comment: Because the family name is fco and not comfortaa. Why do you think the package name must be identical to font name? The family name of times is ptm, of helvetica phv, the tex gyre fonts have names like qhv etc.

Comment: I have just learned that concept. Thank you very much for your help!